# Regular expression for UK phone number - variations for all plausible options

Tags: javascript, regex

So, after some user confusion, I need to tweak a regular expression for all phone number variations you could think of.

I currently have the following regular expression:

```
^[+]?[-\s.]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s.]?[0-9]{4,6}$
```

It matches fairly well, but I'd like to be able to match this to the following variations:

- +44 01726 400480
- +44 1726 400480
- +44 01726 400 480
- +44 1726 400 480
- 01726 400480
- 01726 400 480

**N.B.** I understand that similar questions to this have been asked previously, but I feel that adding the above variations would be perfect for the community.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Without sounding belligerent, I don't think this is duplicate because the matches I can see on other questions do not cover all of the outlying cases.

Comment: @Cerbrus Without sounding belligerent, I don't think this is duplicate because the matches I can see on other questions do not cover all of the outlying cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^\+?(?:[- .]?\d{2})?[- .]?\d{4,5}[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{3}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/DiJLVb/2

Note that `[0-9]` simplifies to `\d`, and that character sets with only a single character in them simplify to just that character. Also note that using a literal space is a bit more reliable than `\s` if you only want to match a literal space - otherwise, other whitespace characters like newlines will be matched too, which may well not be desirable.

Details:

- `\+?` - Optional plus
- `(?:[- .]?\d{2})?` - Optional leading two digits
- `[- .]?\d{4,5}` - Four or five digits
- `[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{3}` - Six digits, possibly separated by a character

Comment: Worked like a charm - thank the heavens for you regex experts! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=105302

`^[+]?[-\s.]?[(]?[0-9]{2,3}?[)]?[-\s.]?([0-9]{3,4})?[-\s.]?[0-9]{3,6}[-\s.]?[0-9]{3,6}$`